# #Error in report field when pushing SSRS (.rdl) in PowerBi report server

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, powerbi

So, my problem is the following :

I set up a report (.rdl) using Microsoft Report Builder.
In that report, I use a MySQL datasource (I'm connecting to it using ODBC connection string).
In my table i have the following data types :

- varchar
- text
- mediumblob (base64 images stored in DB)

When i run the report locally, everything's working as expected, but when i push the report in Report Server or if i connect to the report server in Report Builder, the images are not showing anymore (blank field and the text datatype field show #Error.

I've spend some time now trying my luck by using visual Studio, modifying a ton of settings in the field expression and other things that i don't remember....

If anyone have an hint, i would be grateful